# Unix/Linux backup account that does not update LAST ACCESS files metadata

Tags: backup, accounts, file-metadata

I'm actually wondering if on Unix/Linux systems, there is a equivalent of "Backup Operators" on Windows.

On Windows, being member of this group allows to open files without updating their LAST ACCESS metadata.

Is there anything similar on Unix/Linux ?

I know that remounting the whole volume using "noatime" option can give this ability, but this is a non-sense as this would require no one accessing datas at time of backup.

Here is the context of the question :

- The Unix/Linux server is hosting CIFS shares and is a production server accessed by other systems/services.
- A Windows server connecting to the Unix/Linux one thru CIFS shared will open files to backup/search in their content.
- The goal is to avoid update LAST ACCESS metadata on opened files because there might be an archiving solution that would rehydrate files and/or consider files as being updated.

Can someone please help on this subject ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer roaima.
Actually, here is the deal :
- The Unix/Linux server is hosting CIFS shares and is a production server accessed by other systems/services.
- A Windows server connecting to the Unix/Linux one thru CIFS shared will open files to backup/search in their content.
- The goal is to avoid update LAST ACCESS metadata on opened files because there might be an archiving solution that would rehydrate files and/or consider files as being updated.

I hope it's better with these informations

Comment: Anyone ?
Am I all alone with this question as a lot of people is concerned ? :)

Comment: Please be patient! I don't know what timezone you're in, but the west coast USA is only just starting, and Australia/China/New Zealand, etc. are (probably) still asleep. Those in UK/Europe will have been working all day and may only now be able to start considering a response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent of the "Backup Operators" functionality, and as far as I'm aware there is no easy per-file or per-user method of avoiding setting `atime` on file access.

Most extN filesystems are mounted with `relatime` rather than `noatime`, so access time is updated for reading at most once per (24 hour) period.

Personally, I backup either using a snapshot or by working from modification time (`mtime`). The snapshot approach might work well for you unless you rely on `atime` to determine whether or not to include a file in a backup set. If that's what you're doing then you would need to use `mtime` instead of `atime`. (Why would you want to include/exclude files based on whether or not they'd been accessed? Surely it would be better to include them only if they'd been changed. Am I misunderstanding your requirement?)